# Simulate escape key press without jquery

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jqlite

I would like to (unit) test my AngularJS app without resorting to using jQuery, as jQuery will replace jqLite and in the real app jQuery won't be available either.
There are real differences between jQuery and jqLite, so having jQuery available to AngularJS in the unit tests is a risk.

Most of my tests work fine without jQuery now, but I need to trigger a keydown for the escape key, something I can only find out how to do using jQuery. How would I do that in Javascript in a cross browser fashion?

The directive listens for escape keydowns like this:

```
body.bind('keydown', handledEscapeKey);
var handledEscapeKey = function(e) {
  if (e.which === 27) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scope.$apply(scope.hideTooltip());
  }
};
```

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if( window.KeyEvent ) {
  var evObj = $document.createEvent('KeyEvents');
  evObj.initKeyEvent( 'keydown', true, true, $window, false, false, false, false, 27, 0 );
} else {
  var evObj = $document.createEvent('UIEvents');
  evObj.initUIEvent( 'keydown', true, true, $window, 1 );
  evObj.keyCode = 27;
}

elm[0][0].dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can checkout Angular UI @ http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/

```
<textarea ui-keydown="{27:'keydownCallback($event)'}"></textarea>
```

Comment: The question was not "how can I best listen to escape keypress", but "how can I simulate ESC keypress without jQuery".